# Difference Function

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, difference

I don't understand how I could get a result of 4 for difference on the following:

```
          col_a               col_b
201 E. Rudisill       2535 E 10th St.
6039 Bunt Drive     408 W. Petit Ave.
```

`difference(upper(a), upper(b))` returned 4 for both rows.

How is this possible? They do not sound anything alike?

Comment: The `Soundex` values for all four strings is "0000". That isn't surprising if you read the [Soundex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soundex) article at Wikipedia. It was designed for matching names, not street addresses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOUNDEX converts an alphanumeric string to a four-character code that is based on how the string sounds when spoken. May be the above string starts with numbers the soundex() return '0000'.

**Similar Question** : [Soundex with numbers as String parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12519696/soundex-with-numbers-as-string-parameter)